# Sending json response for a POST request in node js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to write a web service in node js. So, basically when someone calls my service through POST and passes the appropriate parameters as JSON then my service should receive the data, call the flutterwave API and get a response and send the response back to the client in JSON. I have been able to do most of it except the sending the response back in JSON format. So, far I am able to print the response in my console but I want to send the response to the client in JSON format. How do I do that ?

```
app.post('/pay', function (req, res) {
    var jsonString = '';
    var validateoption = req.body.validateoption;
    var authmodel = req.body.authmodel;
    var cardno = req.body.cardno;
    var cvv = req.body.cvv;
    var expirymonth = req.body.expirymonth;
    var expiryyear = req.body.expiryyear;

console.log("Validateoption",req.body.validateoption);
console.log("id",req.body.id);


   /* req.on('end', function () {
        console.log(JSON.parse(jsonString));
    });*/
    flutterwave.Card.tokenize({
        "validateoption":validateoption,
        "authmodel":authmodel, /*Only NOAUTH and BVN are accepted*/
        "bvn": "(Optional:Only needed where authmodel is BVN)",
        "cardno":cardno,
        "cvv":cvv,
        "expirymonth":expirymonth,
        "expiryyear":expiryyear

    }, function(err,body)

    {

    });
});
```

The response I am getting from Flutterwave is in JSON format and I want to send the JSON response back to my client. This is what I receive

```
 body:
  { data:
     { responsecode: '00',
       redirecturl: null,
       avsresponsemessage: null,
       avsresponsecode: null,
       responsemessage: 'Completed Successfully',
       otptransactionidentifier: null,
       transactionreference: null,
       responsehtml: null,
       responsetoken: 'YtUyf18D8l06GloAUTH' },
    status: 'success' },
 flutterwaveRequestSuccessful: true,
}
```

Comment: Just add in `function(err,body)` => `res.json(body);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `res.json()`:

```
function(err,body){
   res.json(body.data);
});
```